# Is it a good practice to have an AWS EMR standing cluster always running structured streaming?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-kafka, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming job which takes data as input from AWS MSK (Kafka) and write to AWS S3. Is it a good idea to have a standing AWS EMR cluster always running the same? Or are there better ways to manage this infrastructure?

Please let me know if you need further details.

Answer (score 0):

You need some worker pool that is consuming and writing.

Your other options include using EKS instead or YARN on EMR to run Spark, or you could not use Spark and use Kafka Connect S3 Sink instead on an EC2/EKS cluster.

Comment: Thank you, but we want to use Spark Structured streaming for other future implementations.

That being said, if we use EKS, it won't be a managed service, and the monitoring would become an overhead, right?

P.S. EMR on EKS has been tried, but the AWS support we are getting for the service is very minimal. So we are planning to bunk it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. EKS is "managed by AWS", your apps would not be. Your apps are also not "managed" in EMR, only the cluster itself. The monitoring wouldn't be an overhead since you can usually just `helm install` some type of Prometheus monitoring or other exporter like Datadog/NewRelic